# Why do methods in Django's built-in ModelBackend return an empty set when an obj is passed in?

Tags: django

I was reading through [source code of Django's built-in ModelBackend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py) while researching how to write my own authentication backend and was surprised to find that the `get_group_permissions`, `get_all_permissions` & `has_perm` methods just return an empty set when a non-None `obj` is passed in. Why do they do that? I realize Django doesn't have built-in row-level permissions, but wouldn't, in the default scheme, permissions for the object just inherit from the table-level (Model class) permissions that the Permission/Group tables represent for a given user? I.e., if I have obj, why doesn't the built-in auth backend just lock at obj's Model (i.e. class) to determine whether the user has a given permission pertaining to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit test for that code indicates that this was added to satisfy [ticket 12462](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12462). As to whether this is correct, it is not clear what the code calling these functions this way would have been expecting. But since you know how it works, you can plan accordingly.